# How to show/hide items with checkbox value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, hide, show

I want to show/hide items that have a particular class (the one of the corresponding input).

So here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#fcheck input").click(function(){
    if ($("#fcheck input").is(":checked"))
    {
        //show the hidden div
        var zzz = $(this).val();
        $('li' + zzz).show("fast");
    }
    else
    {
        var yyy = $(this).val();
        $('li' + yyy).hide("fast");
    }
  });

});
```

And my "form":

```
<form id="fcheck">
            <input type="checkbox" name="school" value="school" id="school" /><label for="school">School</label>
        </form>
```

And for example, what should toggle:

```
<ul><li class="school">taratata</li></ul>
```

So the thing is that I don't manage to get the correct syntax for the selector...

And my code is pretty ugly as well I guess.

Regards :)

Comment: Your code seems ok - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/93tMa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#fcheck input").click(function(){
    if ($("#fcheck input").is(":checked"))
    {
        //show the hidden div
        var zzz = $(this).val();
        $('li.' + zzz).show("fast");
    }
    else
    {
        var yyy = $(this).val();
        $('li.' + yyy).hide("fast");
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Well, no. I want to target "li" that have class of the value of the checkbox. Sorry for the misunderstanding, I edited my post.

Comment: @flintsburg: Then use the `class` selector instead. See my updated answer.

Comment: @flintsburg Just change where it says `li[value` to `li[class`

Comment: @brenjt: unfortunately something that simple doesn't work for elements which has multiple classes (and the JavaScript attribute for `class` is actually `className`!).

Comment: @flintsburg: You should change your `if ($("#fcheck input").is(":checked"))` to `if ($(this).is(':checked'))` to target the elemenr that was just clicked, rather than **allll** inputs inputs within '#fcheck'.